# How to configure UIVisualEffectView to get effect like the one we have with default UIAlertController with type action sheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I want to achieve visual effects like action sheet in my custom view which got rounded corners.

```
containerView = [UIView new];
[containerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1]];
[self addSubview:containerView];

UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *effectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc]initWithEffect:blurEffect];    
[containerView addSubview:effectView];
```

I have added subviews to container view and I applied corner radius like this.

```
-(void) addCornerRadius:(float) cornerRad isTopSide:(BOOL) isTopSide
 {
    cornerRadius = cornerRad;
    isTop = isTopSide;

    UIBezierPath *maskPath;
    UIRectCorner  *corner;
    if (isTopSide)
    {
         corner = (UIRectCornerTopLeft|UIRectCornerTopRight);
    }
    else
    {
       corner = (UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight);
    }

         maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds
                                 byRoundingCorners:corner
                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(cornerRad, cornerRad)];

       CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
      maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
      maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
     self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}
```

But I'm not anywhere close in creating effect like the one created by `UIAlertController`. How to achieve this ?

Comment: What is self.bounds?? Is it self.view.bounds or have you set property?

Comment: Above code is present inside UIVIew subclass so self implies view